# Networkx graphs python

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1,2,3,4])

G.add_edge(0,4,weight =2.0)
G.add_edge(0,2,weight =3.0)
G.add_edge(0,1,weight =5.0)
G.add_edge(4,3,weight =4.0)
G.add_edge(4,2,weight =10.0)
G.add_edge(4,1,weight =6.0)
G.add_edge(2,3,weight =2.0)
G.add_edge(2,1,weight =1.0)
G.add_edge(1,2,weight =2.0)
G.add_edge(1,3,weight =6.0)

nx.draw(G,with_labels=True,font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

I need to set the coordinates of each node. And

```
G.node[0]['pos'] = (0,0)
```

is not working I dont even know why. How can I set the each node any help?
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRGbS.png)

ı have to set coordinates of each nodes like this but it create randomly position.

This is my error:

```
AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'node'
```

Comment: If you don't know why it's not working, maybe give us the error and we can figure out?  Edit your question to include your error.

Comment: Edited, check it out

Comment: OK thank you.  That will give others a head start on solving your problem 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graph does not have attribute `node` (it was obsoleted in networkx 2.0). The name of the attribute is `nodes`:

```
G.nodes[0]['pos'] = (0,0)
```